# Serve public files with reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

*Node.js 8.9.1, hapi 16.6.2, h2o2 5.2.0*

There is a [reverse proxy](https://github.com/hapijs/h2o2) route to use an external API.

```
  {
    method: '*',
    path: '/api/v2/{param*}',
    handler: {
      proxy: {
        host: 'host.net',
        port: 8100,
        protocol: 'http',
        passThrough: true,
        localStatePassThrough: true
      }   
    }   
  }
```

I need to serve AngulaJS UI on the same Node.js server. The following route is added.

```
  {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{param*}',
    handler: {
      directory: {
        path: 'public'
      }   
    }   
  }
```

Now I see UI. But I can't get data from the external API anymore

```
curl -XGET localhost:8001/api/v2/birds
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}
```

How can I serve both UI and reverse proxy on the same Node.js server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work by making the reverse proxy route more specific. Now I have three reverse proxy routes instead of one.

```
  {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/api/v2/{param*}',
    handler: {
      proxy: {
        host: 'host.net',
        port: 8100,
        protocol: 'http',
        passThrough: true,
        localStatePassThrough: true
      }   
    }   
  },
  {
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/api/v2/{param*}',
    handler: {
      proxy: {
        host: 'host.net',
        port: 8100,
        protocol: 'http',
        passThrough: true,
        localStatePassThrough: true
      }   
    }   
  },
  {
    method: 'PUT',
    path: '/api/v2/{param*}',
    handler: {
      proxy: {
        host: 'host.net',
        port: 8100,
        protocol: 'http',
        passThrough: true,
        localStatePassThrough: true
      }   
    }   
  }
```